# Вопрос по синтаксису javascript. Вложенные методы перебора массива

Tags: javascript

Всех приветствую!
Есть двумерный массив, который хотелось бы вывести в таблице.
Как это сделать при помощи метода map в js? Какой должен быть синтаксис?
Что-то типа такого:

```
function runMap(data){
    const newArr = data.map( (tr, index) => {
        "<tr>"+
            tr.map( (td, i) => 
                "<td>"+ td +"</td>");
            +"</tr>";
        });
    return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ваш код в целом рабочий, но допущена пара ошибок:
Во первых вы в первом map забыли вернуть значение, и у вас возвращается undefined
Во вторых map возвращает массив, а массив со строкой лучше не складывать.

```js
function runMap(data){
    const newArr = data.map( (tr, index) => "<tr>"+
        tr.map( (td, i) => "<td>"+ td +"</td>").join('')+"</tr>"
    );
    return newArr.join('');
}

console.log(
runMap([
[1,2],
[3,4]
])
);
```

Comment: А во втором мап лишняя ;